# iPhone to iPhone communication over internet

Tags: ios, communication

I want to know how 2 iPhones can exchange data. I'm coding in swift and need some examples for a simple app development. I have explored APNS and do not want to go that route of provisioning provider service/server. I found some GameKit examples but not sure if that would be something I can really use as my app is not really a game, also I saw that some classes are deprecated on iOS8. I need my communication to go over internet. Not use Wi-Fi/Bluetooth. Any other options? Please advise.

Comment: you've got to have a server in between, that would synch either devices, once you have that, its simple

Comment: You can use iCloud sync to exchange data among ios devices. This only works if both devices are logged-in using same iCloud ID. Or else you will have to use some web service.